# SVM qp solver in sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, quadratic-programming

I study SVM and I will implement svm using python sklearn.svm.SVC.

As i know SVM problem can be represented a QP(Quadratic Programming)
So here i was wondering which QP solver is used to solve the SVM QP problem in sklearn svm.

I think it may be SMO or coordinate descent algorithm.

Please let me know what the exact algorithm is used in sklearn svm

Comment: Any code to share?

Answer (score 1):

Off-the-shelf QP-solvers have been used in the past, but for many years now dedicated code is used (much faster and more robust). Those solvers are not (general) QP-solvers anymore and are just build for this one use-case.

sklearn's SVC is a wrapper for [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) ([proof](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)).

As the link says:

> Since version 2.8, it implements an SMO-type algorithm proposed in this paper:
>
> R.-E. Fan, P.-H. Chen, and C.-J. Lin. Working set selection using second order information for training SVM. Journal of Machine Learning Research 6, 1889-1918, 2005.

([link to paper](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/quadworkset.pdf))